# How to remove product permalink ICON from images on Betheme in WooCommerce

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, product

Within WooCommerce, in BeTheme theme, I couldn't remove the permalink icon from my features products and images.

[image]

With CSS, is there a way to not display the transparent icons that come up on product image permalinks?

Is there any solution for that?

My website link: https://hawky.ma/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To hide the icon link you can use the following CSS rule:

```css
li.product div.image_links { 
    display:none !important; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you , it works on features products

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's probably a ::before or ::after pseudo-element. What's the link, I can take a look and send you a code

Comment: here's the website link  https://hawky.ma/